# Most efficient way to tackle NATs?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm trying to make a distributed system, where each node has it's own server and client.
Let the server client for one node be AServer and AClient, and for the second node be BServer and Bclient.

Currently, the operation is such, that the AClient sends datagram packets from any free port say Y, and is always listening (with AServer) on a particular port say X. The BServer side always replies to packet address at a predefined port X.

This does not work behind a NAT because of the port mappings that NATs create. Since the X for the NAT at which BServer replies may not be mapped to the correct AClient
So these are the solutions and problems I thought of to solve this issue,

Any new ideas are more than welcome, and I would want to hear about the efficiency as well as ease of implementation for all of these ideas.

1. Solution AClient Sends packet from the port that AServer listens at. BServer replies to the port associated with the Apacket. (I tried this out, but it showed errors, I am not sure if UDP is fully duplex or how well multiple writes on a socket are handled)
2. Use jpcap to create an Apacket which has it's source port as the port I am listening at(say X), and is sent through a different port(say Y), so that when the BServer replies to the Apacket port, it reaches the port I was listening at(X).
3. Create an AClient thread which listens for a response from the BServer, and then sends that response to itself as loopback on the port it's AServer listens at. (How efficient is it to send loopback packets?)
4. Create an AClient thread which listens for a response from the BServer, and then use thread synchronization to prevent multiple simultaneous writes on the object being written to from the information received with the AClient and the AServer.

I'm afraid of the answer being point 4. Also, feel free to ask for any code if needed!

Comment: Are the clients and servers not on the same network?

Comment: You're seem to need to do NAT hole punching, which is abit painful and non-trivial, the wikipedia articles have a few useful references, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching . If your server is not behind NAT (only the client is), you have a different problem though - but it's quite unclear what it is - if the server replies to the same port as the source port in incoming packets, NAT takes care of mapping it back to your internal port -that's what NAT does.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more understandable..!